# Definable over $(\mathbb{N},0,S)$, $A$ or $\mathbb{N}\setminus A$ is finite

Tags: model-theory

Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ be defineable over $(\mathbb{N},0,S)$. Then is $A$ or $\mathbb{N}\setminus A$ finite. $S$ is here the successor-function $S(n)=n+1$.

Hello,

I have a question to this task. 
First of all it is clear, that every natural number is definable about this model.
$1=S(0), 2=S(S(0)), ..., S^x(0):=\underbrace{S(S(...S(0)...))}_{\text{x-times}}=x$ for $x\neq 0$.

I think a proof through contradiction is not wise, since it should need quantifire elimination, which I would like to avoid.

I want to understand what the problem is, when $A$ is a set with $A$ and $\mathbb{N}\setminus A$.

For example: $A=\{0,2,4,6,...\}$ the set of every even natural number.

The following should not be an appropriate formula:

$\varphi\equiv ((v_0=0)\wedge (v_1=S^2(0))\wedge (v_3=S^4(0))\wedge\dotso\wedge v_n=S^{2n}(0))$

This formula uses the natural numbers, which are definable, but also multiplication (2n).
But the main point is, that this formula is infinite, because it contains infinite terms.

So I guess that the problem for those sets is, that you have to give a "rule" how to generate the elements of $A$. My example is simple, and yet a rule, just using 0 and S, should not exist. 
So when A gets more complex, like the set of prime-numbers, it is impossible to define it.

Can I proof this by differentiation of the cases:

1. A is finite
2. A is infinite

Case 1 is easy. When A is finite I can give the formula just like in the example. I can list every element.

When A is infinite, and I know $\mathbb{N}\setminus A$ is finite, I can use negation and list the elements of $\mathbb{N}\setminus A$, but I should show, that A is really finite.
Here I use that $A$ is definable. So a formula exists. When I know I can not give a "rule" to generate the elements, it should be simple. But how do I show, that such a rule does not exist?

Would this work?
Or are my thoughts missleading and wrong?

Thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using quantifier elimination?

Comment: I want to avoid quantifier elimination, because I do not really know how it works, and think it is lavish.

Comment: You can do this by induction on the complexity of the  formula defining $A$ but you might as well prove quantifier elimination.

Comment: So I should try a proof by contradiction. And show by induction on the complexity of the formula, that you can not define $A$ iff $A$ and $\mathbb{N}\setminus A$ are infinite sets?

Comment: I tried seriously to prove your claim directly bypassing QE. I failed, it seems yet another example of "the law of conservation of misery" in math.

Comment: Which kinds of formulas do you need to observe when you try a QE?